# JSON "flat" serialization with Java

Tags: java, json

I am looking for a JSON library that supports defining the serialization depth. Ideally I would like a library that handles all primitive types and java.lang and the rest will be sent to a custom handler. In my case the custom handler should generate a Link object with URL and class of the element (for my REST API).

Here an example:

```
Person : String name,  Car car
```

Would be serialized to

```
{
“name”:”Peter”, 
Link : {“class”:”my.company.Car”, “url”:”http://www.mycompany/myapp/Car/5”}
}
```

Any ideas which library I could use (and enhance)? 
Kind regards,

Daniel

Comment: `Link` should also be quoted or this won't be valid JSON. Doesn't matter for the sake of the question, but noting just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I need to define the serialization depth (the last time I looked a gson that was not possible). Futhermore I want to register a handler for all non primitive types and non java.* types.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

- [Jackson Wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)
- [Jackson in 5 Minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

AS you can see you can use simple and complex data-binding rules, and there's a streaming API which will allow you to limit the exploration's depth.

Answer (score 0):

If GSON does not fit your needs, I recommend [JsonMarshaller](http://code.google.com/p/jsonmarshaller/).  It is highly configurable and customizable yet strives to be simple.  It also has a very active user and developer community.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want actual control for serialization depth (as mentioned) or not -- your explanation rather suggest you want to be able to add custom serializers.
Now: if you really need limits (like only shallow copy), you could check out [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/), which supposedly has explicit control over serialization depth.

Otherwise, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) and [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) at least have full bean serialization as well as allowing custom serializers.